# How to forbid BACKGROUND image rotation in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, background, rotation

I have an activity and **I want to keep rotation**, however I do not want to rotate background image. Could somebody help me with this one? Here is my code:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_test"
    tools:context=".Activities.MainActivity">

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Means you want to on rotation for your phone but not for your app right?

Comment: I want rotation (I want to all the textviews and other elements to rotate), but I want to keep the background as it is on Portrait mode.

Comment: On your place - I would create drawable-land folder in resources, and put there background_test rotated, then when you will rotate phone, system will recreate activity, and all your elements will be on new places, and as background will be used resources from drawable-land folder

Comment: Thats an option, but I would therefore store additional (and the same) images this way. I want to avoid that, because it increases APK size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do this without coding. The best way would be checking the orientation in your activity and rotating the bitmap accordingly. The "quick win" solution would be this:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:rotation="@integer/rotation"
               android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/background"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

And override rotation in the ressource folders: `<integer name="rotation">90</integer>` in `values-land` and `<integer name="rotation">0</integer>` in `values`.

Comment: If I do this, I have following output: http://imgur.com/pAXR6wZ . The image width is not matching screen's.